# Printing using Flex Burrito in Android,Ipad,Blackberry

Tags: android, apache-flex, ipad, printing, mobile

I 'm thinking about developing a restaurant application using Flex Burrito.

Is there anyone who can tell me if it possible to print from an Android enabled device to a WIFI printer / kitchen printer? (is it possible to do this also on an IPAD, Blackberry?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Print? 
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/cloudprint/docs/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

AirPrint for the iPad. However this is currently available only for HP printers. http://www.apple.com/ipad/features/airprint.html. From a Blackberry you need to do it using a custom created app. There are also some 3rd party apps created for the BB. Check http://thinkabdul.com/2007/10/02/free-beamberry-blackberry-suite-to-view-print-documents-via-bluetooth-usb-store-pdf-ms-office-zip-files-on-rim-41/

Hope this helps. If so, +1 :)